# OTA on Pycom gPy

Tags: ota, micropython

I have been searching desperately for documentation on how to do OTA update 
on both source code and firmware on Gpy devices.
I have seen the samples (https://github.com/pycom/pycom-libraries/tree/master/examples/OTA),
Which uses WiFiOTA, but no syntax for how to use OTA with LTE CAT-M1.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There are two things you should look at: 
1. Can you connect over LTE and get any data at all?
2. If 1 is true then OTA should be possible UNLESS your LTE connection is bandwidth restrained in some way. Keep in mind the standard say PEAK download speed is 1 Mbit/s.

Try to do the first thing and then work on the second. I hope this helps get you started.